# FTP List format

Tags: ftp

I'm writing an embedded ftp server, and I cannot get the listing format correctly. The server works completely, only programs like FileZilla cannot interpret the listing format. Here's a sample listing:

```
-rwxr--r--  1   owner   group 640   1970 01 01  test
-rwxr--r--  1   owner   group 13440 1970 01 01  test.html
-rwxr--r--  1   owner   group 512   1970 01 01  test2.txt
```

Which is basically:

```
permissions[tab]number?[tab]owner[tab]group[tab]filesize[tab]date[tab]filename
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Yvan

Comment: There is no standard format for FTP LIST output. Different servers use different formats. Which one are you trying to emulate?

Comment: A UNIX one - it's an embedded server for the iPhone written in C#. But I've found the problem: My directory listings were not properly aligned, and my file listings were. Now it opens up in FileZilla correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, you need to use spaces instead of tabs.  Here's a sprintf from another embedded FTP server that should work:

```
sprintf(line, "%s   1 %-10s %-10s %10lu Jan  1  1980 %s\r\n",
    permstr, username, username,
    length,
    filename);
```

`permstr` is set to a string like `"-rw-rw-rw-"`.

As for date formats, these two should work, with the top used if the date is more than 6 months old:

```
if (dfmt)
    sprintf(buf, "%3.3s %2d  %04d", month_name, month_num, year);
else
    sprintf(buf, "%3.3s %2d %02d:%02d", month_name, month_num, hour, minute);
```

Answer (score 7):

Since you did not specify the programming language, I thought I would give my 2cents to this....

```
permissions[tab]number?[tab]owner[tab]group[tab]filesize[tab]date[tab]filename 
                ^^^^^^^                                      ^^^^
             no of inodes                      Dates can vary, it can be year on its own or Month, Day
```

I have decided to include the C# regexp's below to show, this can be adapted to suit your needs,

```
            private Regex ftpUnixListInfo = new Regex(
                @"(?" +
                @"(?[-|d|r|w|x]+)\s+" +
                @"(?\d+)\s*" +
                @"(?\w+)?\s+" +
                @"(?\w+)\s*" +
                @"(?\d+)\s+" +
                @"(?\w+)\s+" +
                @"(?\d{1,2})\s+" +
                @"(?:(?\d{2}\:\d{2})|(?\d{4}))\s+" +
                @"(?.+))",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
                | RegexOptions.Compiled);

            // Regex for Microsoft FTP Server
            private Regex ftpMsListInfo = new Regex(
                @"(?" +
                @"(?\d+-\d+-\d+)\s+" +
                @"(?\d+\:\d+(AM|PM))\s*" +
                @"(?((?\)|(?\d+))\s*)" +
                @"(?\w+))",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
                | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Notice the fact, there is no tab, it is purely spaces...and be careful, some FTP clients can read the listing as either MSDOS or Unix...

Comment: What does the "number of inodes" mean?

Comment: The whole FTP LIST approach is still of limited use because on UNIX the file time part is missing and on Windows the seconds are missing. It's better to retrieve just the file names with NLST and then for each file retrieve the file time and size using MDTM and SIZE. libcurl has support for this.

Answer (score 1):

The typical ftp server would shell out to `ls -l` for the directory listing.  I believe this output contains space characters which align the output, not tab characters.

The only way you can be certain as to why FileZilla is not parsing your directory listing is to get the open source for FileZilla and watch what is happening in the debugger.  But I think you can make progress simply by duplicating the output of `ls` as exactly as possible, including whitespace.